# AngularJS help (explanation) $scope $attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, attributes

Quick question on explanation and how to track `$scope` and `$attributes`.
Friend told me best way to learn is to take someone elses code and rewrite it, figure out where and what is, or why. And so far i learned whole lot.

Need small clarificaiton! :)

Thing is, lets say i have in my foods.html following code:

```
<div id="food-navigation-panel">
    <div class="something-food">    
        <div class="eatSomething">
            <h3 class="eatMe">
                {{food.$attributes.tasty_bacon}}
            </h3>
            <div class="edit-food__preference">
                {{fruits}}
            </div>
            <div class="edit-food__salt" ng-show="userFavorites">
                +{{vegetables}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>       
</div>
```

So.. I can track this `{{fruits}}/{{vegetables}}`

```
$scope.fruits = healthy.get("fruits");

$scope.vegetables = healty.get("vegetables");
```

And they both are in `healthy.js`

However, where is `{{food.$attributes.tasty_bacon}}` ??

Also whats the differnce between `{{food.$attributes.tasty_bacon}}` and `{{food.attributes.tasty_bacon}}`      //Without "$".

Any help would be appriciated!
Thanks!
I can't seem to find it anywhere in my files.

Comment: Thanks ADreNaLiNe-DJ for formatting help! Any other help I can expect!?

Comment: it appears you have a controller, using controller as syntax (somewhere not provided here) named `food`. It also appears that controller is likely a controller for a custom directive (also not provided here). You have not provided enough information to determine an answer with certainty.

Comment: still, should i look for var foods somewhere?

Comment: As I said, you've not provided enough information. May I recommend you take a step back from your friend's advice? Go to https://angular.io/tutorial and complete the tutorial from start to finish. You'll have better luck.

Comment: Of-course! Thanks a lot!